# How to keep old and new version of record until a supervisor approves the changes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 project in which I have to keep record of field changes with certain attributes. Example:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public String PropertyOne { get; set; }

   // Need to keep track of these properties
   [RequiresSupervisorKey]
   public String PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

As soon as one of the fields is changed, it requires a supervisor to approve of these field changes. 
Until the changes have been approved the record will be in a pending state, and I somehow need to keep the old record and the new record until such time!

What is the best practices regarding storing these records? Should I have 2 records in the table in the database or should i have a audit table that can store this data until it has been approved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd save them in one table too. Use a combined key for identifying a unique row. Row ID with autoincretment id. and datetime as the second part of the combined key. When a 3rd row can store the state. This allows you versioning as well. If you select the field for display you select by id order by datetime desc where state is approved limit 1. Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: But this also depends on the size and speed of your database and it's records. For really huge system I'd rather suggest using a second table to keep track of the changes. My best practice is to give both tables always hat the same schema like described above.

Comment: Although everyone has given execellent feedback, i would say that this is most relevant to my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is my .02 from other projects but I would add a version or state column to the table and keep n number of records in the table.  I don't know if its possible in your system for the record to be changed by two different users with different changes, but in situations like this that is usually the case.  An audit table is an acceptable solution but in general I prefer to keep things in one table.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep both records in the table (old and new) with an extra field for status (such as active, pending,  delete, disapproved) (or what ever statuses you think you need).

Then I would create a view that shows only the active records (used for most purposes) and one that shows only the pending records (uses for the supervisor approval page).

I would create a trigger on the table to ensure only one record was active at a time. So if a supervisor changed a record from pending to active, it would take the old record and change it to the delete status. If a supervisor disapproved a change, it would go to the disapproved status.

To keep the table nimble (you indicate no need to permanently store the old statuses), I would have a job that runs at night to delete all records in the delete or disapproved status.